# Scio (Apache Beam) BigQuery struct (Record) type issue

Tags: google-bigquery, record, beam

I`m facing an issue during ingestion process of a BigQuery table which contains RECORD (STRUCT) fields.

The Apache Beam (I`m using Scio with Scala) load process extracts a JSON file with a flat values for the RECORD fields. As shown below:

`"organization_fields":"{org_status_acordo=false, org_inadimp=false, org_status_averb=false, cnpj_do_cadastro=}"`

While exporting the same record directly from BigQuery, the JSON file contains:
 `"organization_fields":{ "org_status_acordo":"false", "org_inadimp":"false", "org_status_averb":"false", "cnpj_do_cadastro":"" },`

I think this is the cause of throwing error:

"Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Flat value specified for record field"

Is there any limitation in using Apache Beam (Scio) ingestion BigQuery tables with RECORD data type?

Thanks for helping.

Find out if it`s possible to ingest BigQuery tables with RECORD data type using Apache Beam (Scio Distribution)

Comment: Could you provide the sample code? As mentioned in this [document](https://spotify.github.io/scio/io/BigQuery.html#:~:text=As%20of%20Scio%200.11.,available%20using%20SBT%20option%20bigquery.) record datatype is supported.

Comment: Hi @BrunoFaleiros, Is your issue resolved? Does this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/type-safe-bigquery-in-apache-beam-with-spotifys-scio-c519fd44553d) help you?

Comment: In order to get answers you will need to add a snippet with the code that is reading the BQ table.